# Using mod_rewrite for split testing on different designs in different dirs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In order to test if a new design is going to be useful, we're doing A/B testing on it. However, the design integrates a large number of files so we don't want to have to keep moving them around.

Is it possible to use mod_rewrite to mask the fact that we've moved both into their own subdirs?

In other words, someone visits http://www.ourdomain.com/ and they see the design located in "public_html/old/" or "public_html/new/" depending on which we have set to show in .htaccess. However, they never know the designs are in subdirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /old/$1 [L]
```

replacing the instances of `old` with `new` as needed.

Comment: This seems to work with everything except for static images.  For instance, if I have an img element with src="images/logo.png" then it is broken when viewed in the browser.  I found it has to be changed to "/new/images/logo.png" in the code.  Why this selective application with some images and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @EcomEvolution not sure why that's wouldn't be working, but it sounds like a relative-path issue. Try adding a `<base href="/">` (or whatever the appropriate base path should be) to your page headers and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it, but it did fix another problem with the URLs on the site.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @EcomEvolution Try adding these 2 lines before the `RewriteRule`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`